# Using WebDriver Extensions to upload file on the Grid

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

Hello im attempting to use WebDriver extensions for selenium, however, at the point of trying to upload a file im becoming unstuck. Locally the file uploads through use of robot e.g: `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`

However on the grid the robot is not working as intended. How am I to file upload to the webapp using Selenium with WebDriver extensions?

Comment: Use AutoIT for the operations instead of Robot class , Robot classes are highly unstable

Comment: use sendkeys on a `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are trying to upload a file from your local machine to the app?
The robot commands you are firing will be applied to the machine that the script is running on (where java is executing), they are not passed over to the node machine.

> **From Documentation:** 
>   All you need to do is use the sendKeys command to type the local path of the file in any file field. This works like a charm in all drivers. When moving this test to a remote server (such as, for example, our Selenium 2 Cloud), all you need to do is use the setFileDetector method to let WebDriver know that you're uploading files from your local computer to a remote server instead of just typing a path. Almost magically, the file will be base64 encoded and sent transparently through the JSONWireProtocol for you before writing the fixed remote path.

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
...
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.id("fileupload"));
upload.sendKeys("/path/to/file.jpg");
driver.findElement(By.id("upload")).click();
```

[See the tutorial](https://saucelabs.com/blog/selenium-tips-uploading-files-in-remote-webdriver)